# R.main cannot be resolved - None of the other answers have worked

Tags: android, eclipse

So like others I have this little bit of code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

The problem is that `main cannot be resolved or is not a field`. `main` in the code is underlined in red.

What I have tried due to other answers:

1. Inserting an import com.project.appname.R;
2. Insured there is no import android.R;
3. Deleted all the imports and then pressed shift+ctrl+o (then checking import android.R was not inserted)
4. Checking my layout in the folder res-->layout --> activity_main.xml file
5. I also tried to change the code to include activity_main instead of just main.

I have cleaned the project and rebuilt it every time I tired each suggestion and error has still not gone away.

I am using Eclipse, Juno, as well as Android and Google plugins.

Any suggestions?

Edit:
Ok. In the folder res>layout> activity_main.xml is the correct name.

I have tried to type

`setContentView(R.layout.activitymain);` and  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

but the error is still there.

When I type 
        `R.layout.`  and then wait for the suggestions the first thing on the list is `activity_list_item : int - R.layout` (There is no other suggestions in the list that include the word main or activity?)

Cannot attach list due to only being new on here and not enough reputation

Comment: Your layout file name is activitymain.xml is not main.xml

Comment: Are you sure it's called "activitymain.xml"? I'd expect it to be `activity_main.xml` (note the underscore). Try using `R.layout.activity_main`

Comment: You're confusing everyone.  Please edit your post and be exact.  The identifier after `R.layout.` has to be the same as your layout XML filename without the XML extension.  Exactly what is your layout XML filename, and is it in `/res/layout` somewhere?

Comment: Type `R.` and wait.  Select `layout` from the auto-completion list.  Then type another dot, so you have `R.layout.` Wait for the list to popup again. What's in the list?

Comment: @Simon I have edited my answer at the top, may be to do with the list as Simon has suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

to

```
setContentView(R.layout.activitymain);
```

Unless you have a layout called main.xml in your layout folder

Comment: Ok. In the folder res>layout> activity_main.xml is the correct name.

I have tried to type 

        setContentView(R.layout.activitymain);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

but the error is still there.

When I type R.layout.  the first thing on the list is activity_list_item : int - R.layout (There is no other suggestions in the list that include the word main?)

Comment: Check your R.java file to make sure it generated the id for main_activity. gen > your_package > R.java. Also did you create the xml file by going to new > android > android xml file? If not, it probably didn't automatically generate the id

Comment: No I did not create the xml file like how you said. I think it has generated it though. Heres the code from the R.java file regarding activity_main  

    <pre> <code>  public static final class layout {
        public static final int activity_main=0x7f030000;'

Comment: @Simon After trying to work out why activity_main would not come up in the suggestions list, I just cleaned the project typed the r.layout. and then if the file name activity_main did not come up I typed it in anyway. The red line then underlined out.acti which suggested to me that the error should have disappeared. I cleaned the build with no luck so I decided to close and reopen eclipse and this has solved my problem. Initially I had not named the file correctly. Therefore I am marking this as the answer. Also Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

This

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

needs to be

```
setContentView(R.layout.activitymain);
```

Since that is the name of your xml file that is what you inflate in `setContentView()`. It is currently looking in "res/layout" for a file named `main.xml` when it should be looking for `activitymain.xml` or whatever the name of the xml file is that you want to use for your `layout`